# Concatenate two JSON objects without jQuery

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have two JSON objects that I want to create one object out of, with either Angular or plain JavaScript (no jQuery). Angular.extend didn't seem to get me what I wanted, and instead did more of a merge.

```
{
  "field1-1": 1,
  "field1-2": 2,
  "field1-3": 3,
  "field1-4": "four",
  "field1-5":
  {
    "field1-1-1": 5.1,
    "field1-1-2": 5.2
  }
}
```

And

```
{
  "field2-1": 21,
  "field2-2": 22,
  "field2-3": "three",
  "field2-4":
  {
    "field2-1-1": 4.1,
    "field2-1-2": 4.2
  }
}
```

I want the end result to be:

```
{
  "field1-1": 1,
  "field1-2": 2,
  "field1-3": 3,
  "field1-4": "four",
  "field1-5":
  {
    "field1-1-1": 5.1,
    "field1-1-2": 5.2
  }
},
{
  "field2-1": 21,
  "field2-2": 22,
  "field2-3": "three",
  "field2-4":
  {
    "field2-1-1": 4.1,
    "field2-1-2": 4.2
  }
}
```

Comment: it seems as though you actually want an array of two objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all!

I was trying to create a conglomerated object of multiple objects to send as the overall object for a rest call from angular to a javaEE based API that had an object as a parameter as well as a dynamic variable for the REST url. I was under the assumption that the objects needed to not have a key in the json, but I was wrong.

So the object I send is basically now:

```
"dynamicID": "keyValue",
"object1":
{
  "field1-1": 1,
  "field1-2": 2,
  "field1-3": 3,
  "field1-4": "four",
  "field1-5":
  {
    "field1-1-1": 5.1,
    "field1-1-2": 5.2
  }
},
"object2":
{
  "field2-1": 21,
  "field2-2": 22,
  "field2-3": "three",
  "field2-4":
  {
    "field2-1-1": 4.1,
    "field2-1-2": 4.2
  }
}
```

Which I did from simply creating a new object:

```
$scope.restObject = {"dynamicID": $scope.keyValue, $scope.object1, $scope.object2}
```

Answer (score 6):

So you want an array:

```
var array = [object1, object2];
```

```js
var object1 = { "field1-1": 1, "field1-2": 2, "field1-3": 3, "field1-4": "four", "field1-5": { "field1-1-1": 5.1, "field1-1-2": 5.2 } },
    object2 = { "field2-1": 21, "field2-2": 22, "field2-3": "three", "field2-4": { "field2-1-1": 4.1, "field2-1-2": 4.2 } },
    array = [object1, object2];

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

If you like to get a single object, then you can use this proposal.

It iterates over the array with the objects and then over the keys of an object. The values from the original object are assigned to the corresponding property of the new object.

```js
var object1 = { "field1-1": 1, "field1-2": 2, "field1-3": 3, "field1-4": "four", "field1-5": { "field1-1-1": 5.1, "field1-1-2": 5.2 } },
    object2 = { "field2-1": 21, "field2-2": 22, "field2-3": "three", "field2-4": { "field2-1-1": 4.1, "field2-1-2": 4.2 } },
    object = function (array) {
        var o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
                o[k] = a[k];
            });
        });
        return o;
    }([object1, object2]);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I was trying to create a conglomerated object of multiple objects to send as the overall object for a rest call from angular to a javaEE based API that had an object as a parameter as well as a dynamic variable for the REST url. I was under the assumption that the objects needed to not have a key in the json, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm mistaken, your desired result looks like a simple array with both objects in it:

```
var result = [objectOne, objectTwo];
```

That is quite different than wanting to concatenate (or merge) two objects into a single object (which is what `angular.extend` or `Object.assign` would do.

Answer (score 4):

Your end result isn't actually valid JSON. Assuming the objects are variables named `object1` and `object2`, you could create an array like this:

```
var objectArray = [ object1, object2 ];
```